# How can I merge and update a comma separated string to an existing column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've a table as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileInfo] 
(
    [FileId]         INT          NOT NULL,
    [FileAttributes] VARCHAR(512) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([FileId])
);
```

DataType to upsert the above table

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[FilesInfo_List_DataType] AS TABLE 
(
    [FileId]         INT          NOT NULL,
    [FileAttributes] VARCHAR(512) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([FileId])
)
```

Stored procedure to upsert the above table:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FileInfo_Save]
    @FilesList [dbo].[FilesInfo_List_DataType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN
            UPDATE f
            SET f.FileId = fl.FileId,
                f.FileAttributes = fl.FileAttributes
            FROM
                [dbo].[FileInfo] f
            INNER JOIN 
                @FilesList fl ON f.FileId = fl.FileId

            IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
            BEGIN
                COMMIT TRAN;
            END
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ---------- OMMITTED --------
    END CATCH
END
```

Now I want to modify the update statement to satisfy the below conditions.

1. If `FileAttributes` is null or empty, update it with the incoming value.
2. If `FileAttributes` is non empty, split the existing value by comma, do the same for the incoming value, merge both the lists of strings without duplicates, order the final string collection in alphabetic order, then join them all back using comma as separator and set it as the new value.

**Case 1**: When value is empty, set the incoming value.

The incoming value is

```
(FileId, FileAttributes) => (3, 'approved,reviewed')
```

Table before update:

| FileId | FileAttributes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | final,finance,order |
| 2 | protected,read_only,recovered |
| 3 |  |

Table after update:

| FileId | FileAttributes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | final,finance,order |
| 2 | protected,read_only,recovered |
| 3 | approved,reviewed |

**Case 2**: when value is not-empty and the incoming value is

```
(FileId, FileAttributes) => (3, 'approved,archive,marked_for_delete')
```

The `FileAttributes` is a comma-separated text field. The incoming string may or may not contain some of the values already present. The existing and the incoming values should be merged without duplicates and written back as alphabetically ordered and comma-separated string.

Table before update:

| FileId | FileAttributes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | final,finance,order |
| 2 | protected,read_only,recovered |
| 3 | approved,reviewed |

Table after update:

| FileId | FileAttributes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | order,final,finance |
| 2 | read_only,protected,recovered |
| 3 | approved,archive,reviewed,marked_for_delete |

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: SQL Server. The code added here is a pseudo code. To better explain the requirement. Also, re-designing the tables is not an option. The actual tables are much more complex and just one column has the update logic as described in the question.

Comment: The real question is why are you storing delimited data in the first place? Ideally you should fix your design and store the data in a *normalised* format. Then, if you need to *present* the data in a delimited format you can do that then.

Comment: Because there are plenty of other columns and we don't want to duplicate all those values to have 1 to n mapping between file id and attributes. These kinds of upserts are very rare. Delimited data (partial or full) is used to upsert and whatever gets stored will be consumed as is. The individual values are not queried anywhere else.

Comment: *"Because there are plenty of other columns"* sounds like you think the solution is a different type of denormalisation. You should have a separate table for your `FileAttributes` data.

Comment: Well, this is pretty easy to achieve. What you need is to create a correlated subquery where you create a new string which contains old + "," + new values, then split the string by ",", then do a distinct of values and then do a STRING_AGG back together ordered by name. Of course all this should handle NULLs on both sides correctly, but it's pretty easy as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SQL Server 2017 and later you may try something like this:

https://dbfiddle.uk/P4d8pmw-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileInfo] 
(
    [FileId]         INT          NOT NULL,
    [FileAttributes] VARCHAR(512) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([FileId])
);

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[FilesInfo_List_DataType] AS TABLE 
(
    [FileId]         INT          NOT NULL,
    [FileAttributes] VARCHAR(512) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([FileId])
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FileInfo] ([FileId], [FileAttributes])
VALUES
    (1, 'order,final'),
    (2, 'protected,read_only'),
    (3, '');
GO

DECLARE @FilesList [dbo].[FilesInfo_List_DataType];

INSERT INTO @FilesList ([FileId], [FileAttributes])
VALUES
    (1, 'final,finance,order'),
    (2, 'protected,read_only,recovered'),
    (3, 'approved,reviewed');

SELECT * FROM FileInfo

UPDATE f
SET f.FileAttributes = 
    CASE 
        -- If existing is empty, set it 
        WHEN f.FileAttributes IS NULL OR LEN(TRIM(f.FileAttributes))=0 THEN fl.FileAttributes
        -- If not empty, merge and sort the existing and incoming values
        ELSE (
            SELECT STRING_AGG(v, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v ASC)  AS result
            FROM (
            SELECT Lower(value) as v FROM STRING_SPLIT(trim(f.FileAttributes), ',')  WHERE LEN(value)>0 
            UNION  -- union does DISTINCT
            SELECT Lower(value) as v FROM STRING_SPLIT(trim(fl.FileAttributes), ',') WHERE LEN(value)>0
            ) a
            )
        END
FROM
    [dbo].[FileInfo] f
INNER JOIN 
    @FilesList fl ON f.FileId = fl.FileId;;

SELECT * FROM FileInfo
```

It uses STRING_AGG which is SQL Server 2017 and newer and STRING_SPLIT  which is SQL Server 2016 and newer.

This UPDATE command should produce the result:

```
UPDATE f
SET f.FileAttributes = (
            SELECT STRING_AGG(v, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v ASC)  AS result
            FROM (
            SELECT Lower(value) as v FROM STRING_SPLIT(trim(f.FileAttributes), ',')  WHERE LEN(value)>0 
            UNION 
            SELECT Lower(value) as v FROM STRING_SPLIT(trim(fl.FileAttributes), ',') WHERE LEN(value)>0  ) a
            )           
FROM
    [dbo].[FileInfo] f
INNER JOIN 
    @FilesList fl ON f.FileId = fl.FileId;
```